# Exclude outliers in python

Tags: python, statistics, knn

I have a list of numbers here which needs to be processed before finding the number/numbers which best explains the variance. In this case, it is very obvious that the 1b and -1b should be removed because they skew the data's std dev. After excluding, we see that -998,523 and -2,000,126 should be selected as they can explain 99% of the sum of the remaining figures. *edit* these 2 numbers are what I'm looking for; they should not be excluded

Question here is what is the best way to exclude outliers? I'm thinking of K-nearest neighbours but it seems like an overkill. Tried IQR, doesn't seem to work well.

Thanks in advance!

```
 1,000,000,000  
 4                0%
 41               0%
 20               0%
-89               0%
-441              0%
-100,005          3%
-998,523          33%
-2,000,126        66%
 51,651          -2%
 5,176            0%
-1,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the largest outlier as the value the most distant from the average; remove this value, and find the next largest outlier, etc...

```
def largest_outlier(nums):

    avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
    delta = [abs(num-avg) for num in nums]
    outlier = max(nums, key=lambda x=delta: abs(x))

    return outlier


nums = [4 ,41, 20, -89, -441, -100005, -998523, -2000126 , 51651, 5176]
numbers = nums[:]

while numbers:
    outlier = largest_outlier(numbers)
    numbers.pop(numbers.index(outlier))
    print(outlier, numbers)
```

#### output:

```
-2000126 [4, 41, 20, -89, -441, -100005, -998523, 51651, 5176]
-998523 [4, 41, 20, -89, -441, -100005, 51651, 5176]
-100005 [4, 41, 20, -89, -441, 51651, 5176]
51651 [4, 41, 20, -89, -441, 5176]
5176 [4, 41, 20, -89, -441]
-441 [4, 41, 20, -89]
-89 [4, 41, 20]
41 [4, 20]
20 [4]
4 []
```